# Custom action in personal menu - language

Tags: solution-package, visual-studio-2013

I have created personal menu item  for Sharepoint 2013. How to create personal menu that picks language automatically the same way as other SP menu items do? 
I have this in Elements.xml:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="DeactivateAccount"  GroupId="PersonalActions" Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu" Sequence="1000" Title="Deactivate Account" Description="Click here to deactivate your account" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <UrlAction Url="javascript:void(DeactivateAccout());"/>
  </CustomAction>

</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the way of doing that. 
Added resource files to the project, and the  reference to it in code: 
Title="$Resources:Resources,Deactivate_label"

```
<CustomAction Id="DeactivateAccount"  GroupId="PersonalActions" Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu" Sequence="1000" Title="$Resources:Resources,Deactivate_label" Description="$Resources:Resources,Deactivate_label" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
        <UrlAction Url="javascript:void(DeactivateAccout());"/>
      </CustomAction>
```